# How to capture the Okta Add Person details to our company database?

Tags: authentication, okta, okta-api

I'm pretty new to Okta, please help me with this scenario.

In Okta we have an option called **Add Person** can be navigated from **users>>People>>Add Person**

[image: Add Person form]

Once we send an invite to the user that details will be captured on Okta **People** dashboard with the status of **Pending user Action**

[image: Okta People dashboard showing user status Pending]

At this moment, once we send invite to the user and got the user status as **Pending user Action**, we need insert this user record into our **company database** with status as **Invited**.

And once user Activate the okta account via email we sent in the first step, user status will be changed to **Active** on Okta People Dashboard.

[image: User status transition to **Active**]

So once user registered successfully, status turns active on Okta, then our database record inserted for that user should be updated to **Active** status.

I see some features in okta like **Inline Hooks and Event Hooks** etc.. is it possible to achieve this using any of those features or else please throw some light if there is any other ways to do this.

Thanks in advance.